# How to export PCA from Weka

Tags: weka, pca

I am performing a PCA operation on my dataset using WEKA (filter-unsupervised-principal component). Once I apply, I am getting the PCA. However I am not able to export the PCA in a separate file for further processing. How do I export first 3 PCA in a csv or a txt file from Weka?

Answer (score 0):

The "Save..." button at the top right of the Preprocess tab in Weka Explorer will export your PCA-filtered data. You will be prompted for the name and type of file you'd like to export to.
You can control the number of allowed principal components via the -M parameter to the filter, or you could export to a .csv file, open in a spreadsheet application, and remove all but the first three columns.